# Java Stack Methods: Size, duplicate, reverse

Tags: java, stack

The stack is given in the task and I'm supposed to implement 3 methods:

1. a method that tells you the size of the elements in stack
2. a method that duplicates the top value of stack
3. a method that reverse the stack / changes its order

I have already implemented the first 2 methods with success, they are working well.

```
public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Element element = top; element != null; element = element.next)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

public void dupe() {
        if (top == null)
        {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        push(top());
    }
```

For the reverse method I got problems, is it even possible to reverse a stack just by using that stack? Aren't 2 stacks needed here?

Complete code is here:

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;


public class IntStack {

    private Element top;


    public IntStack() {
        top = null;
    }


    public int pop() {
        if (top == null)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        int value = top.getValue();
        top = top.getNext();
        return value;
    }



    public int top() {
        if (top == null)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return top.getValue();
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return top == null;
    }


    public void push(int value) {
        Element newTop = new Element(value);
        newTop.setNext(top);
        top = newTop;
    }


    public String toString() {
        Element runingElement = top;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (runingElement != null) {
            sb.append(runingElement.getValue()).append("\n");
            runingElement = runingElement.getNext();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public void dupe() {
        if (top == null)
        {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        push(top());
    }


    public int size() {
        int count = 0;
        for (Element element = top; element != null; element = element.next)
        {
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }


    public void reverse() {


    }
```

Comment: What if you swap the top and bottom elements?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot create a temporary stack, and push on to it the pop of the main stack while it is not empty, and then set the internal stack reference to the temporary stack?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use another stack :(

Comment: This is why I don't care for some CS teachers. At no point in a real world scenario would you ever reverse the stack itself w/o using another stack as was suggested. You are not learning anything here that will be of value to you in the real world. The only lesson I can see that s/he is teaching is how to swap the position of elements. Even if I have a basic list and I want to reverse the order, I'll make another list and then add the elements in backwards.

Comment: Are you allowed to use an array? Because once you **know** the `size` you can construct an array of that length.

Comment: @Frisch yeah actually no one said an array isn't allowed :D

Comment: @blahfunk, completely agree, and just to expand, in reality one would also need to worry about concurrency. And I do not get this "avoid a duplicate stack, but an array would be fine"; it is silly; substituting one type of object for another doesn't teach anything either.

Comment: @blahfunk There is a point, point is to write an efficient algorithm. Even in real world using copy to do this for a sufficiently large dataset would not work.

Comment: Wait, you are just not allowed to use another stack, but you can use an array? If you can use an array, can you use an ArrayList? If so, that's your answer right there. Pop off the stack into the arraylist and it will be reversed when you are done.

Comment: @11thdimension Your best programmers are lazy and want to find the quickest path to the solution, albeit your superior programmers are lazy, but will also want to make the computer work efficiently.

Comment: @blahfunk Agreed, but it's important to know the best way specially when learning.

Comment: @11thdimension We are going way off track here, so this is really a rhetorical question, but if you needed to reverse the order of a stack for some reason in your code, honestly, how are you gonna do that? I'd immediately create a second stack and pop the first one into that, then point to that stack instead. Swapping the literal order of my stack would be the absolute last thing I would do. Too easy for something to go wrong there and then the whole stack is fubared.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that reverses the stack without using an array or another stack. There may be more optimal ways to achieve the result, of course. In essence, the top of the stack has its next set to null, and it goes through each of the elements, setting the element's next to the previous node. At the end, it sets the internal top to the last element. This approach is not thread safe.

```
    public void reverse() {
        if (isEmpty() || top.getNext() == null) {
            return;
        }

        Element prev = top;            
        Element cur = top.getNext();
        Element end = null;

        // set the top of the stack to have it's next point to nothing
        prev.setNext(null);

        // while we have something to process, loop
        while (cur != null) {
            // keep the next from the current
            Element tmp = cur.getNext();

            // update the next to point to the previous
            cur.setNext(prev);

            // set the previous to where we are now
            prev = cur;

            // need to find the end; update to where we are now
            end = cur;

            // update our current to the temp; could be null
            cur = tmp;
        }

        top = end;
    }
```

Sample test driver that will load 10 elements (0 - 9):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStack stack = new IntStack();

    // ensure reverse does nothing on empty stack
    System.out.println("empty stack");
    System.out.println(stack.toString());

    System.out.println("Reversing.");
    stack.reverse();

    System.out.println(stack.toString());

    // make sure does nothing on single entry
    System.out.println("pushing 0");
    stack.push(0);
    System.out.println(stack.toString());

    System.out.println("Reversing.");
    stack.reverse();
    System.out.println(stack.toString());


    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Pushing " + i);
        stack.push(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Stack after test load:");
    System.out.println(stack.toString());



    System.out.println("Printing size.");
    System.out.println(stack.size() + "\n");

    System.out.println("Reversing.");
    stack.reverse();
    System.out.println(stack.toString());


}
```

Sample output:

> empty stack
>
> Reversing.
>
> pushing 0
>     0
>
> Reversing.
>     0
>
> Pushing 1
>     Pushing 2
>     Pushing 3
>     Pushing 4
>     Pushing 5
>     Pushing 6
>     Pushing 7
>     Pushing 8
>     Pushing 9
>
> Stack after test load:
>     9
>     8
>     7
>     6
>     5
>     4
>     3
>     2
>     1
>     0
>
> Printing size.
>     10
>
> Reversing.
>     0
>     1
>     2
>     3
>     4
>     5
>     6
>     7
>     8
>     9

Comment: Yours is shorter and better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method to reverse the stack.

```
public void reverse() {
    if( top == null || top.next == null) {
        return; //do nothing
    } if (top.next.next == null) {
        Element last = top.next;
        last.next = top;
        last.next.next = null;
        top = last;
    } else {

        Element secondLast = top;
        Element last = top.next;
        Element current = top.next.next;
        secondLast.next = null;

        while(true) {
            last.next = secondLast;

            if(current == null) {
                top = last;
                break;
            }

            secondLast = last;
            last = current;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** It can be done almost too easily if we create a doubly linked list.